# Updating MySQL Database of Users With PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am setting up a cron job to execute every hour. I need the script below to pull a value from each user in the database based on a field ID.

Field 18 is a dropdown with values from 0-10. In my PHP below I want to update $val based on Field 18's value. Then pass $val to Field 45 in the database for each user.

Everything works. However, the value being inserted to EVERY user is only based on the LAST user's information. The last user in the database has field 18 set to 4, so 2920 is sent to Field 45 of every user. What am I doing wrong?

Also...I realize this won't look good for potential SQL injections etc. I am just trying to get the functionality set before working on that.

```
<?php
// Create connection
 $con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");

// Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

  $getvalue = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT value FROM mydatabase WHERE thefieldid=18");

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getvalue)) {

  foreach($row as $rows) {


   $num = $rows['value'];

   if ($num == 0) { 
   $val = '660'; }

   if ($num == 1) { 
   $val = '990';  }

   if ($num == 2) { 
   $val = '1590'; }

   if ($num == 3) { 
   $val = '1955'; }

   if ($num == 4) { 
   $val = '2920'; }

   if ($num == 5) { 
   $val = '3885'; }

   if ($num == 6) { 
   $val = '4850';  }

   if ($num == 7) { 
   $val = '5400';  }

   if ($num == 8) { 
   $val = '3885';  }

   if ($num == 9) { 
   $val = '5400'; }

   if ($num == 10) { 
   $val = '7200';  }

   echo $num;
   mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE mydatabase SET value = $val WHERE thefieldid = 45");

}   
}

 ?>
```

Comment: tip, how about an array `$foo('0'=>'660','1'=>'990 ..` instead of that if block, which should be if\else

Comment: agreed. but that still won't fix my issue of every user receiving the variable of the last user in the database. it's a problem with my while/foreach structure I'm guessing?

Comment: Indeed. Here's an example of use with proper naming ...
    `$rows = array();`  
    `while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getvalue)) {`  
    `   $rows[] = $result;`  
    `}`  


and then the foreach $rows as $row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to filter the update to target the particular user in the current row of the loop?

```
e.g $getvalue = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT value, userid FROM 
mydatabase WHERE thefieldid=18");
```

..

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE mydatabase SET value = $val 
WHERE thefieldid = 45 AND userid= $row['userid']");
```